# Set environment variable for Go tests

Tags: go, automated-tests, environment-variables

I am trying to run my Go tests like this, setting an environment variable:

```
FOO=BAR go list ./... | grep -v vendor | xargs -n1 go test -timeout=3s
```

Inside my tests I do:

```
log.Print(os.Getenv("FOO"))
```

Which returns an empty string. Why is FOO not set?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
FOO=BAR bash -c 'go list ./... | grep -v vendor | xargs -n1 go test -timeout=3s'
```

A good explanation why the original command doesn't work can be found in the answer to the question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134735/environment-variables-are-not-set-when-my-function-is-called-in-a-pipeline

Comment: Mind to explain this a bit? ;)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134735/environment-variables-are-not-set-when-my-function-is-called-in-a-pipeline

Answer (score 8):

I like to use [godotenv](https://github.com/joho/godotenv) in [command mode](https://github.com/joho/godotenv#command-mode)

```
godotenv -f ./.env go test ./internal/... -cover
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not how setting variables for pipes works. See:

```
 FOO=BAR echo "AAA" | FOO=WAZ printenv | grep FOO
```